# validation of controller-assigned variables in rails integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm beginning with Rails and currently I got stuck on integration testing of controllers.

I'm trying to validate that if certain values are provided by a user in a form, Active Record generates errors and these errors are passed to a view.

My problem is that I have no idea how to access controller assigned variables (for example - @user) inside integration tests. As I read in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#what-to-include-in-your-functional-tests I can access variables such as @controller, @request, @response but I was also expecting that I can easily access variables assigned by controller.

Unfortunately things such as:
 * @user
 * @controller.user

don't really work :-/

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Rails Version < 5.0**

You can access these variables using `assigns` method with symbol of variable name as a perameter. In example:

```
assigns(:user)
```

Gives you value of `@user` from your controller.

**Rails Version > 5.0**

In rails 5.0 `assigns` and `assert_template` has [been_depracted](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html), so in order to use it as before you need to add:

```
gem 'rails-controller-testing'
```

to your Gemfile.

[Original discussion](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html) why using `assigns` is a bad idea.

Comment: FYI

```NoMethodError: assigns has been extracted to a gem. To continue using it, add `gem 'rails-controller-testing'` to your Gemfile.```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to verify that a certain variable has been assigned in your tests then you can use following statement in your test. This will check whether your @user variable in controller has some value in it or not.If @user has some value in it then the test will pass otherwise it will fail

```
assert_not_nil assigns(:user)
```

And then you can run following command to run your test in terminal

```
 ruby -I test test/integration/your_test_file_name.rb -n test_name
```